# request.user.attribute returning unwanted value

Tags: django, django-views

Why does the following print(owner) return a different value that what's in my model?  Is it possible to get the formattedusername defined below?  I've simplified my def profile(request) and took out my other arguments till I can figure out the solution to getting formattedusername.

```
def profile(request):
    owner = User.objects.get (formattedusername=request.user.formattedusername)
    args = {'user':request.user.formattedusername}
    print (owner)
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', args)

Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
@3-alphas4numeric
[06/Nov/2017 16:18:11] "GET /account/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1416
```

formattedusername in my model is stored in the database as HCA\3-alphas4numeric, it's also defined by the following, it's also the key field in all my other models and there isn't a way around using an integer for the key since it's a pre-existing database:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):



    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
    formattedusername = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, primary_key = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    facility = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    jobdescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    positiondescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    coid = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    streetaddress = models.CharField(max_length=140)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'accounts'
        db_table = "user"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.formattedusername = '{domain}\{username}'.format(
            domain='HCA', username=self.username)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs);
```

Comment: That cannot be a valid username, since it's longer then the `max_length`.

Comment: formatted username is 11 characters, i'm trying to pull the formatted user name into my view not the username.

Comment: `HCA\3-alphas4numeric` is 20 characters

Comment: 3-alpha characters 4 numeric characters, that's how all user IDs are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `print(owner)`, you will print out the value of `USERNAME_FIELD`. That's how `AbstractBaseUser.__str__` is implemented.

```
def get_username(self):
    "Return the identifying username for this User"
    return getattr(self, self.USERNAME_FIELD)

def __str__(self):
    return self.get_username()
```

Comment: Thank you for this Haken, I've been trying to figure this out for the past few days and nobody else seemed to get it based on how i asked the question.

Comment: Is there a way to print out the formatteduser name in the view without changing my USERNAME_FIELD?

Comment: `print(owner.formattedusername)` or override `__str__`